# How to change the value of DataPath in WebSphere MQ 8?

Tags: ibm-mq

I had an old installation of W MQ 7, when I installed a new one  W MQ8, I found out that DataPath is pointing to the old installation :
DataPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ

```
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     8.0.0.4
Level:       p800-004-151022.DE
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Windows (x64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Windows 7 Enterprise x64 Edition, Build 7601: SP1
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
Primary:     Yes
InstPath:    C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ_8
DataPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
MaxCmdLevel: 802
LicenseType: Developer
```

How to change that value ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you uninstall V7 first? Makes a big difference according to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q119400_.htm

Answer (score 0):

It can be set in the file C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ_8\mqs.ini, it is the DefaultPrefix property.